# SATA RAID or SCSI RAID Old IBM Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, sata, scsi, ibm-xseries

Need your help on this one.
One of my SCSI HD failed in RAID 1, thinking about replacing it, but can no longer find 73gb drive on the market (only used available).

**Option 1:**
Clone remaining SCSI HD to 2 new 146gb+ SCSI HD (Ultra320), and possibly face hefty $$$?

**Option 2:**
Clone remaining SCSI HD to 2 new 500gb SATA HD (SATA r.1-1.5gb), and save $$$?

The HD is running Windows 2003, and use primarily for file storage/sharing (50gb+ data), and running a WebMail server (connected to an email linux box).

Please give me advice on which is the best option??

Which cloning software is the best?? 
Sorry I am not familiar with cloning steps, do I setup RAID then clone them? 
Will there be problem moving data from 73gb to 500gb RAID 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the path of least resistance. Parallel SCSI hard drive technology fell out of favor on new servers by the end of 2006. Everything since has seen SATA or SAS. Buy an used or refurbished drive of the same model as the failed disk online (perhaps ebay). I'd recommend purchasing an extra disk as insurance.

Answer (score 1):

With an IBM server, get the FRU (Field Replacement Unit) number for the disk from IBM.  It should also be printed on the label of the dead hard disk if you can pull the disk to inspect it.  IBM may also be able to give you a replacement FRU number if the specific part is no longer in inventory.

Then, either:

1. Buy a replacement part from IBM, based on the FRU number or the FRU number of the replacement item, or
2. Do a google and/or ebay search based on the FRU number and find somebody that has them in stock.  A 73gb disk is a pretty common component for a server.  You will almost certainly be able to find somebody that has the parts in stock.